# Two column div layout, content in right column/div not centering properly

Tags: html, css

I am failing miserably at getting my layout to behave properly with a two column-div layout

There is a content wrapper, then a navigation menu on the left and main content on the right.

For some reason the main content is centering based on the content-wrapper, and not on its own width.  I'm not sure how to get the main-content to center within itself.

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">

<!-- #BeginLibraryItem "/Library/header.lbi" -->
<div id="header"></div>
<!-- END HEADER -->
<!-- #EndLibraryItem -->

<div class="clear"></div>

<div id="content-wrapper">

<!-- #BeginLibraryItem "/Library/navigation.lbi" -->
<div id="navigation">
    <p class="Home-Page-L_Panel"><a href="http://www.twitter.com/kosherCruises"><img src="http://twitter-badges.s3.amazonaws.com/follow_bird_us-b.png" alt="Follow kosherCruises on Twitter"></a></p>
    <p class="Home-Page-L_Panel"><a class="Home-Page-L_Panel" href="#Passover10">Passover</a></p>
    <p class="Home-Page-L_Panel"><a class="Home-Page-L_Panel" href="#KCruises">Kosher Cruises</a></p>
    <p class="Home-Page-L_Panel"><a class="Home-Page-L_Panel" href="#Sukkot">Sukkot</a></p>
    <p class="Home-Page-L_Panel"><a class="Home-Page-L_Panel" href="#GKTours">Kosher Tours</a></p>
    <p class="Home-Page-L_Panel"><a class="Home-Page-L_Panel" href="#JHTours">Heritage Tours</a></p>
    <p class="Home-Page-L_Panel"><a class="Home-Page-L_Panel" href="links/Interesting-Links.htm">Links</a></p>
    <p class="Home-Page-L_Panel"><a class="Home-Page-L_Panel" href="Contact.htm">Contact Us</a></p>
    <p class="Home-Page-L_Panel"><a class="Home-Page-L_Panel" href="index.htm">Home</a></p>
    <p class="Home-Page-L_Panel"><a class="Home-Page-L_Panel" href="#Candle">Candle Lighting</a></p>

    <div><img src="OTBGifs/el_al_whitebkgrd-100W.jpg" alt="El Al It's not just an  airline. It's Israel." width="100" height="24" border="0"></div>

    <div align="left"><a href="http://www.travelex-insurance.com/index.asp?location=05-0686&go=bp;"><img src="Travelex_Images/Linking Graphic_small.GIF" alt="Travelex Insurance" width="100" height="66" border="0"></a></div>


    <p>Time in Jerusalem</p>
    <div align="left">
                <iframe src="http://free.timeanddate.com/clock/i1q3n65d/n676/fn5/tcddd/ahl/bas5/bat6/baceee/pa2" frameborder="0" width="103" height="33"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div><img src="http://www.judaicawebstore.com/AffiliatePro/scripts/imp.php?a_aid=5547af81c16e2&amp;a_bid=3d5614ac" width="1" height="1" alt="" /></div>
    <object width="120" height="600">
        <param name="movie" value="http://www.judaicawebstore.com/AffiliatePro/accounts/default1/banners/JWS_120x600-3.swf?clickTAG=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.judaicawebstore.com%2Fgifts-for-someone-you-love-C906.aspx%23a_aid%3D5547af81c16e2%26a_bid%3D3d5614ac">
        <param name="menu" value="false"/>
        <param name="quality" value="medium"/>
        <param name="wmode" value="Opaque"/>
        <embed src="http://www.judaicawebstore.com/AffiliatePro/accounts/default1/banners/JWS_120x600-3.swf?clickTAG=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.judaicawebstore.com%2Fgifts-for-someone-you-love-C906.aspx%23a_aid%3D5547af81c16e2%26a_bid%3D3d5614ac" width="120" height="600" loop="false" menu="false" swliveconnect="FALSE" wmode="Opaque" allowscriptaccess="always">
    </object>                   
</div>
<!-- END NAVIGATION -->
<!-- #EndLibraryItem -->

<div id="main-content">

<h1>The Site for Kosher Travel</h1>




</div><!-- END MAIN-CONTENT -->

</div><!-- END CONTENT-WRAPPER -->


<!-- <div class="clear"></div> -->
<div id="footer">
</div><!-- END FOOTER -->


</div><!-- END WRAPPER -->
</body>
```

STYLES:

```
/* CSS Document */
body {
    background-image:url(OTBGifs/116a8b.GIF);
}

/* unvisited link */
a:link {
    color: #000099;
}

/* visited link */
a:visited {
    color: #000099;
}

/* mouse over link */
a:hover {
}

/* selected link */
a:active {
    color: #0000FF;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p
{
    font-family: Times New Roman, Times, serif;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 20px;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 18px;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 16px;
}

p {
    font-size: 16px;

}

#wrapper {
    width: 740px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color:#848484;
}

#navigation {
    width: 132px; 
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 0px;
    vertical-align: top;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
    margin:0px;
}

.Home-Page-L_Panel
{
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
}

a.Home-Page-L_Panel
{
    text-decoration: none;
}

#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 113px;
    background-color: #6699FF;
}

#main-content {
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-left: 132px;
    display: inline-block;

}

#content-wrapper {
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Image of current layout showing how the "The Site for Kosher Travel" is not properly centered within its div:

[image: Image of current layout showing how the "The Site for Kosher Travel" is not properly centered within its div]

Comment: Can you post an image of what you are looking for? A sample layout, may be draw in Paint?

Comment: I've added an image showing the bad centering.  Thanks!

Comment: I see that. Now I doubt if you have the same code here  as you have in your  actual page.  Here content-wrapper and main-content is missing the width.

Comment: One moment, I'll edit.

Comment: I have updated the post to show the full code, except for the <head>

Comment: Meanwhile check if this is what you need - http://jsfiddle.net/ta87w2d9/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using text-align: center within the #main-content. I only see it within your h1.

Comment: This modification resulted in no change to the output. Thanks.

Comment: That doesn't do anything!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want the left nav to use 132pixels in width, and the main-content nav to use the remaining screen width.  You need to float your nav container to the left, then for the main-content div, set it to `display: block` and give it `left-margin` equal to the width of the left nav:

```
#navigation {
  width: 132px; 
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 0px;
  vertical-align: top;
  float: left;    <----------- here
}

#main-content {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: block;     <------- here
  margin-left: 132px  <------- and here, increase this to add space between the two columns
}
```

To ensure that any content after `#content-wrapper` renders beneath the whole thing, add a clearfix to your CSS:

```
#content-wrapper:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/bcoom7rn/1/

Comment: If I float the navigation section, won't #main-content flow around the bottom of the navigation if #main-content ends up longer than the navigation?

Comment: That's what the `margin-left` is for on the `#main-content` rule.  That ensures any content in the `#main-content` container is positioned no further left that whatever you set it to.

Comment: Aha!  Thank you.  will try now.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `h1` is NOT centering based on the `#content-wrapper`. It just happens that your container size made it SEEM like it's in the center of the `#content-wrapper`.

Apply these styles to `#main-content`:

```
right: 132px;
left: 0;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
position: absolute;
```

Apply these styles to `#content-wrapper`:

```
position: relative;
```

Remove these styles from `#main-content`:

```
margin-left: 132px;
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: This is good since you can change the width of the #content-wrapper, and it'll still look just fine.

Comment: in this case you are also removing the left margin just like my solution....so     why this is better

Answer (score 0):

I see your full code and see that you have few fundamental issue with the way you have written your layout.

Things you can do:

1. Use `width` for `#main-content`
2. Use float layout

### 1 Update CSS for `#main-content`

```
#main-content {
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    width:604px;
}
```

Notice, I have removed margin-left. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/tg68m6mp/

### 2 Use floats layout. (Good, old way)

Use float on both #navigation and #main-content, also give width and use clearfix div which you already have. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/56bnk5s4/

Answer (score 0):

try this....

```
#main-content { width: calc(100% - 136px);margin-left: auto; };
h1 { text-align: center;  }  /* this h1 is inside main-content div*/
```

Comment: But you need to remove the margin-left: 132px on #main-content for that to work.

Comment: yes,otherwise use float or any other method explained by others....but for every other solution you have to change existing css just like in this case